# What is the problem whit this custom WordPress plugin php code?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

SO I was trying to make a custom payment gateway plugin for woocommerce. This code seems alright but when I upload it to my site my site shows "There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your site admin email inbox for instructions."

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Custom Bkash Payment for WC
 * Plugin URI: 
 * Description: This plugin helps you to add Bkash store payment link to checkout page.
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Classified
 * Author URI: https://example.com
 * License: GPL-2.0 or later
 * License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 * Text Domain: custom-bkash-payment
 */

// Your plugin code goes here.
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' )))) return;

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'custom_bkash-payment_init', 11);

function custom_bkash_payment_init() {
    if ( class_exists('WC_Payment_Gateway')) {
        class WC_Custom_Bkash_Pay_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
            public function __construct() {
                $this->id = 'custom_payment';
                $this->icon = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_custom_bkash_payment_icon', plugins_url( '/assets/icon.png' , __FILE__ ));
                $this->has_fields = false;
                $this->method_title = __( 'bKash Payment', 'custom-bkash-payment');
                $this->method_description = __( 'bKash Payment System.', 'custom-bkash-payment');

                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();
            }

            public function init_form_fields() {
                $this->form_fields = apply_filters( 'woo_custom_bkash_pay_fields', array(
                    'enabled' => array( 
                        'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'custom-bkash-payment'),
                    ),
                ));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to ask ChatGPT. But ChatGPT responded that there was no problem with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have hooked your function incorrectly:

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'custom_bkash-payment_init', 11);
```

You may have meant to pass `custom_bkash_payment_init` not `custom_bkash-payment_init` as the second parameter (there should be an underscore, `_`, between `bkash` and `payment`, not a dash, `-`):

```php
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'custom_bkash_payment_init', 11 );
```